# Who is Wanner from Rosenrock-Wanner (ROW) methods?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, differential-equations, computation

I've spent some time with a search engine trying to find out about Wanner, a person whose surname is mentioned in the name of Rosenbrock-Wanner (ROW) methods primarily used for iteratively solving stiff differential equations, but without much success.

Does anyone know who this person is/was, and the full name of this person?

I apologize if my question does not belong here. In this case please suggest where it can be posted.

Comment: Could this be who you are looking for: [Gerhard Wanner's homepage at the University of Geneva](https://www.unige.ch/~wanner/) - coauthor of [Rosenbrock-Type Methods](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7_7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock-Wanner-Verfahren), it is the Austrian mathematician [Gerhard Wanner](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Wanner_(Mathematiker)).